# Adding Pin for Bluetooth connection on Raspi

Tags: shell, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, passwords

For the security I want to have an PIN before I connect to bluetooth.

i already looked at forums and found following solution, but it didn´t help.?

My bt-agent.service looks like this. But at [Service] ExecStart I added -p /root/bluetooth.cfg.

```
cat <<'EOF' > /etc/systemd/system/bt-agent.service
[Unit]
Description=Bluetooth Agent
Requires=bluetooth.service
After=bluetooth.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bt-agent --capability=NoInputNoOutput -p /root/bluetooth.cfg
RestartSec=5
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGUSR1
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Also in the `sudo nano /root/bluetooth.cfg` i just wrote: `* 1234` for the passwort.
But after i restart my raspi i can´t connect to bluetooth, the option to write an passwort into it didnt appear. When i try to connect it tells me, that im not allowed to connect because of an wrong pin.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You might want to check out https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ also.